# Android Notification Not clickable in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-notifications, android-notification-action

We are facing a problem in unity is, when clicked on the scheduled notification in android. The app does not open.

We have firebase messaging in the app so it uses the activity "**com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity**".

When a scheduled notification appears and we click on them its try to open "**com.unityplayer.UnityActivity**" instead of "**com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity**" maybe this is causing the app not to open.

But, when scheduled notification appears when the app is already open and we kill the app and click on the notification it perfectly try to open activity "**com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity**" and application also opens perfectly.

Do any of you have an idea on how to work around this or a way to fix this. or is this a issue from  Firebase sdk itself. Please share you ideas.

**Unity 2020.3.41f1**
**Firebase Cloud Messaging : 10.0.1**

I Have tried changing the activity name from Mobile Notification but it did not work.

Comment: Anyone else is facing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Use Custom Activity in Mobile Notifications and use this [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mk6J.png)com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity